# auto Update page every day or hour with curl?

Tags: php, curl

Hello How can do auto Update page every day whit curl to get data?

I don't know How do.

I write this code.

```
<?php
include_once ("xpath.php");
 $ch = curl_init ("http://wpu.ir/1hp9j");
    $baseUrl ="http://www.digionline.ir";
    $dom = new DOMdocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($cl);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$produsttitleQuery = $xpath->query("//span[@class='product-page-detail-wrapper-   text']/text()");
 $produstpriceQuery = $xpath->query("//span[@class='product-detail-wrapper-   price']/text()");
 $produstlinkQuery = $xpath->query("//ul[@id='product-page-product']/li/a/@href");


 $data = array();
 for ($x=0; $x<20; $x++){
 $data[$x]['title'] = $produsttitleQuery->item($x)->nodeValue;
 $data[$x]['price'] = $produstpriceQuery->item($x)->nodeValue;
 $data [$x]['link'] =$baseUrl.$produstlinkQuery->item($x)->nodeValue;
}
echo "<pre>";

print_r($data);
?>
```

thank's

Comment: have you tried looking at cronjobs

Comment: I can't work with cronjob

Comment: If you can't have a cronjob you will have to keep a local cache, check its age every time you access it, and refresh it from the remote source if it's too old.

Comment: can you write example code.